# Cut and Paste disabled after WIndows 7 install

Tags: windows

I've got a user that upgraded from XP to Win 7.  She's had some issues with the upgrade that we've almost worked our way through, but one has stumped me.  She can't cut and paste.  The options are there in the context menu, but they don't seem to do anything.

I searched MSDN and didn't find anything.  Has anyone else encountered this particular problem?  Any ideas??

Answer (score 1):

This could be due to misbehaving Context Menu handlers. Check the article [Right-click is slow or weird behavior caused by context menu handlers](http://windowsxp.mvps.org/slowrightclick.htm) out for more details.

Answer (score 0):

If you are copying and pasting from different formats you may be running into a problem.  Facing the same issue I just discovered that "paste special" offered options for pasting text that included text only and html.  I had copied a sentence from a web page (HTML) and was attempting to paste into Outlook (RTF format).  No dice.  All was forgiven by electing "paste special"| text.